# How to correctly match pandas multiindex dataframe multiplication for sparse data

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, multiplication, multi-index

I've searched before posting this, I've found among others [this previous stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109011/pandas-dataframe-multiplication-with-respect-to-multiindex) and I don't think it answers my question.

I have sparse data that I want to multiply together correctly matched by index, where the data is a multilevel index.

I have observations of different `attribute`s for a number of `element_id`s on different dates, but the data is sparse:

[image]

This is my second array `df_weight_at_date` a list of weights for each `element_id` (python to create at bottom of post)

[image]

For each date, I want to multiply values together, so for example in my observed data `A/1/2021-01-15` (0.87) should be multiplied by weight at date `1/2021-01-15` (0.3) for a value of 0.261

If either value is `NaN` then the result is `NaN` and the output frame will have the same shape as the `df_observations` dataframe.

I've tried using `.multiply` but get the error no `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names`

`df_observations.multiply(df_weight_at_date.unstack())`

Expected output for this data

[image]

Bit of a newbie - would appreciate any pointers, thanks

**code to create data frames**

```
df_observations=pd.DataFrame({'observed_date':['2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16','2021-01-16'],
               'element_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                'factor_id':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','A','A','A','A','A','A','F','F','B','B','B','B','B'],
               'observation':[0.87,0.84,0.15,0.6,0.17,0.76,0.03,0.91,0.05,0.38,0.06,0.27,0.92,0.27,0.16,0.71,0.32,0.92,0.88,0.53,0.79,0.15,0.3,0.16,0.36,0.05,0.22,0.73,0.7,0.9]}).pivot(index=['observed_date','element_id'], columns='factor_id', values='observation')


df_weight_at_date=pd.DataFrame({'observed_date':['2021-01-15','2021-01-15','2021-01-15',
                                 '2021-01-16','2021-01-17','2021-01-18',
                                 '2021-01-19','2021-01-20','2021-01-18'
                                ],
               'element_id':[1,3,5,1,3,5,1,3,9],
               'weight':[0.3,0.35,0.35,1,1,0.4,1,1,0.6]}).pivot(index=['element_id'], columns='observed_date', values='weight')
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the expected output

Comment: Yes, definitely - have done that now thanks for the nudge

Comment: I think your solution needs a change in axis to `0`; you could try : ``df_observations.swaplevel() .rename_axis(index={"observed_date": "observation_date"}) .mul(df_weight_at_date.stack(), axis=0).sort_index(level="observation_date")`` You'll probably have some null rows to get rid off

Comment: Thanks - in fcat i messed up and your comment helped me realise that: both frames should have `observed_date` so that they can be joined - the second one erroneously had `observation_date` - I have now corrected that in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting the input frames so that index names match (`observation_date` -> `observed_date`) this now works and is concise enough I think

```
df_observations.multiply(df_weight_at_date.unstack(), axis=0)
```

result
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to unstack `df_weight_at_date`:

```
df_observations.mul(df_weight_at_date.unstack().fillna(1)
                    .reindex(df_observations.index, fill_value=1),
                    axis=0
                   )
```

Output:

```
factor_id                      A       B      C     F
observed_date element_id                             
2021-01-15    1           0.2610  0.2730  0.048   NaN
              2           0.8400  0.0500  0.710   NaN
              3           0.0525  0.1330  0.112   NaN
              4           0.6000  0.0600    NaN   NaN
              5           0.0595  0.0945    NaN   NaN
              6           0.7600  0.9200    NaN   NaN
              7           0.0300  0.2700    NaN   NaN
2021-01-16    2           0.9200     NaN    NaN  0.36
              3           0.8800  0.0500    NaN  0.16
              4           0.5300  0.2200    NaN   NaN
              5           0.7900  0.7300    NaN   NaN
              6           0.1500  0.7000    NaN   NaN
              7           0.3000  0.9000    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time but I dont think this does produce the desired output - I updated the post with the expeted output for this data

Comment: Remove `fill_value=1` inside `reindex`

Comment: Hi, no still produces values for 16/1 when should be 'NaN's I think

Comment: Also remove fillna(1)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
df_weight_at_date.stack().swaplevel().to_frame('A').reindex(df_observations.columns,axis=1).ffill(axis=1).mul(df_observations)
```